# Google API Calendar PHP SSL error

Tags: caching, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I have written a code for fetching Google Calendar events using Google Api Package Php. It works perfectly fine. Just that, once it fetches details of an user. It is caching the details in the server. I am using Centos server. To my knowledge, it has something to do with Google api caching. Because of that I have to wait for 15 mins before another user's details can be fetched else it will show the previous user details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to be a little more specific. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please update the question with some details of your code and error message. I suggest trying the Calendar [PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)